# Why can't I install Plotly package in RStudio? What does the error say?

Tags: r, package, r-plotly, ubuntu-20.04

```r
install.packages('plotly')
```

I try to install the `plotly` package by running the code above in **RStudio**. However, it fails and returns the below. I'm a newbie and I can't read this properly. **What should I do to fix this?**

I also try to install `curl`, `openssl`, and `httr` manually first, but it makes no difference. Also, I'm using **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** if relevant.

```r
Installing package into ‘/home/ariel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’, ‘httr’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/curl_4.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 673779 bytes (657 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 657 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/openssl_1.4.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1207708 bytes (1.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/httr_1.4.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 159950 bytes (156 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 156 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/plotly_4.9.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3709741 bytes (3.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.5 MB

* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/ariel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
--------------------------- [ANTICONF] --------------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
-------------------------- [ERROR MESSAGE] ---------------------------
tools/version.c:1:10: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/home/ariel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’ are not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/ariel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘plotly’
* removing ‘/home/ariel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/plotly’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘plotly’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpJQIJ6f/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Maybe installing `libcurl4-openssl-dev` is solves your problem (such as `sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev`).

Comment: The error message tells you what system dependencies you need to install. These dependencies are not R specific so you need to install them outside of R. Look for the text that says "Try installing" and install however is appropriate for your OS.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for clarifying this! Everything went back normal after `sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev` and `sudo apt install libssl-dev`. And I know a little bit more about reading the error messages. You can make the comment an answer if you want. Give you some points after I accept it. Thanks again!